# Using epsilon-delta definition to find limit involving $\sin x$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I need to show $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^2-16}{x+\sin x}=0.$$ I am mostly unsure how to simplify the expression  $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left|\frac{x^2-16}{x+\sin x}\right|<\epsilon$$ due to the $\sin x$ involved. 
I got up to 
$$\left|\frac{x^2-16}{x+\sin x}\right|<\left|\frac{x^2-16}{x+1}\right|,$$ but I'm not sure whether this is the right or how to proceed.

Comment: The limit is $\infty$, not $0$.

Comment: Note that $|x+\sin(x)|\ge|x-1|\implies |\frac 1{x+sin(x)}|\le|\frac 1{x-1}|$ and not $x+1$ at denominator as you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

> The limit is $\infty$, not $0$.

Recall that $0\le x+\sin(x)\le  x+x=2x$.  Then, given any number $B>0$, however large, and for $x\ge 4\sqrt{2}$

$$\frac{x^2-16}{x+\sin(x)}\ge \frac{x^2-16}{2x}\ge \frac14 x>B$$

whenever $|x|>\max(4\sqrt{2},4B)$.  And we are done!

Comment: This is more of a nitpick, but you need to mention that the function is positive for large $x$. Apart from that +1.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh No, it was not nitpicking at all.  I've edited to clarify.  And thank you for the up vote!

Comment: sorry I'm incredibly new to this, but where does the $4\sqrt{2}$ come from and why do we take max($4\sqrt{2}, 4B$)?

Comment: $x^2-16\ge \frac12x^2$ when $x\ge 4\sqrt 2$.  And we begin by bounding $x$ as such (i.e., $x\ge 4\sqrt 2$).  We see that beginning with this bound that for any given $B>0$, $\frac{x^2-16}{x+\sin(x)}>B$ when $x>4B$.  So, what if we chose $B=1$.  The $\frac{x^2-16}{x+\sin(x)}$ would not be larger that $B$ for all $x>4B$.  But it is true when $x>4\sqrt 2$.  So, in general, if $x>\max(4\sqrt 2,4B)$, then $\frac{x^2-16}{x+\sin(x)}>B$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark